Example of Critical Path
If $F$ takes on its minimum at a path $\omega_0$, and if the derivatives $\frac{\mathrm{d}F\left(\bar{\alpha}(u)\right)}{\mathrm{d}u}$ are all defined, Milnor states in his Morse Theory that clearly $\omega_0$ is a critical path, but I have difficulty verifying it.
For an arbitrary variation $\bar{\alpha}$ of $\omega_0$, it satisfies that $\bar{\alpha}(0)=\omega_0$ and $\alpha(u,t)=\bar{\alpha}(u)(t)$. It immediately follows that $\alpha(0,t)=\bar{\alpha}(0)(t)=\omega_0(t)$. Now I’m trying to prove that
$$\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}F\left(\bar{\alpha}(u)\right)}{\mathrm{d}u}\right\vert_{u=0}=0,$$
but I failed. I suppose probably because I don’t understand the definition of $F$, so could you give me some hints?

Definition of F
Differentiate F(α(u)) with respect to u and then use Leibniz Rule to move the derivative inside the integral.
Since () is an arbitrary variation and (0)= _0, it implies that the derivative term must independently be zero at =0. Hence, This verifies that _0 is indeed a critical path for .

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Why is the derivative term independently zero at $=0$? And your Definition of F confused me.

F is a functional, which takes a function (in this case this path $\omega$) as the input and returns a scalar value. In the context of variational calculus, F could generally be expressed as $F(\omega) = \int_a^b L(t, \omega(t), \omega'(t))dt$, where L is the Lagrangian that depends on the position () and the velocity ′().

As for the derivative term, it's because α(u) represents an arbitrary variation. If the integrand were not zero independently, there would exist some variation α(u) for which the derivative $\left.\frac {dF(\alpha(u))}{du}\right\rvert_{u=o} \neq 0$. This contradicts the assumption that $\omega_0$ is a critical point where F is minimized.
